# Am I over or underwatering my bird of paradise?

Tags: indoors, tropical

About two months ago I acquired a large bird of paradise plant. I keep it indoors, about 15 feet away from a north facing window.

Its leaves have been browning and curling, which I believe is either a sign of under or overwatering. I worried the soil might not be well-draining enough so I watered it relatively infrequently, about once a week.

I live in a small apartment, so it's difficult for me to de-pot the plant to see if it has root rot. How can I figure out what the problem is and save my plant?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I actually think it's possible I have both over and underwatered it......hoping I can find a balance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out what I was doing to the poor plant, and it was indeed a combination of over and under watering but more importantly: I wasn't giving it enough sunlight! I only have north facing windows, so I placed this bird of paradise right next to one and it immediately began to improve, and started to push out new growth within about a month. I've been watering it via a small wine bottle that is placed into the soil.